# How to generate image from a multi-dimensional array (or matrix)

Tags: php, arrays, bitmap, png

Is there a way to convert a 3-dimensional array (or matrix) into an RGB image in PHP? Assuming I have a 3D array (width * height * color) of 1000*250*3, how can I convert it into a png image? Maybe the function `imagesetpixel()` can do the work in a loop. But an efficient way might help to improve response time.

Answer (score 0):

Write the data raw into a binary file, then use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) to convert it to any file format this supports.

From [Supported Image Formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php):

> Raw: red, green, and blue samples. Use `-size` and `-depth` to specify the image width, height, and depth.

which suggests a command line such as

```
convert your_data_file -colorspace RGB -size 1000x250 efficient_output.png
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But I cannot execute command on the server. My current PHP Version is 5.3.3 and imagick module version is 2.2.2.